# AutocompleteTextView is not Getting Enabled

Tags: android, autocomplete, textwatcher

I have a weird situation where one of the AutocompleteTextView is getting enabled and second is not no matter what. I an edit text etSerial and if that has some value then edit text (etDesign) and autocomplete textview atShade should get disabled but when i clear text of etSerial, bothe etDesign and atShade should get enabled.

atShade and etDesign are getting disabled but when text is cleared from etSerial then only etDesign gets enabled.

nothing happens on atShade clicking after clearing etSerial(Before entering value in etSerial it was showing values properly)

i also added toast to see  if it is enabled or not, textview is showing that it is enabled but i am not getting cursor on clicking atShade

my code is :

```
private void initAutoText(final TextView tv) {
tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(tv == etSerial){
                if(etSerial.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    atShade.setEnabled(true);
                    etDesign.setEnabled(true);
Toast.makeText(OrderBookingActivity.this,String.valueOf(atShade.isEnabled()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            if(tv == etSerial){
                if(!etSerial.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                etDesign.setEnabled(false);
                atShade.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried **setFocusable(true)** and **setFocusable(false)**  for autocompleteTextView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of your if block inside afterTextChanged() method.
Try following code:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        if(tv == etSerial){
            if(!etSerial.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
               etDesign.setEnabled(false);
               atShade.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you change? it is exactly same as my code @nnn

Comment: Check the scope of  inner if loop. Braces are missing in your code.